# Export Embedded Excel Workbook in a PowerPoint slide to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, export, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation w/ an embedded Excel Workbook, name:  `ThisWorkbook`
I need to export `ThisWorkbook` into an Excel File.

Thank you

Comment: The keyword 'embedded' is incorrect here; people are using 'embedded' here to mean "embedded programming", not "a document that's embedded".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the worksheet is called "ThisWorkbook"?  `ThisWorkbook` is the reference that is used to refer to the workbook in which the code module resides.  On inserting a worksheet it will be named "Worksheet in Presentation1", or similar.

To save the file you can use the following in an Excel code module (Alt+F11 when the worksheet is active)

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="mypath\myfilename.xls"
```